# Django user_id from django db missing in application models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, project, django-database

A few days ago I started this tutorial on Django:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1mokevMWk

The video is about how to set up your first django project, using some libraries from django, as well as bootstrap to style your website. He goes on about how to setup the database, website and everything else you need for the example of a todolist website and at the end of the video series he goes over setting up Users, as well as user specific todo lists. I tried recreating the process and up to the point of the user specific todo lists it was all very understandable and easy to follow. Yet as I tried implementing pretty much the last step of the implementation i get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /create/
table main_todolist has no column named user_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/
Django Version: 5.0.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
table main_todolist has no column named user_id
Exception Location: C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\backends\\sqlite3\\base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during:  main.views.create
Python Executable:  C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.0
Python Path:    
\['C:\\Users\\brenneckeo\\Desktop\\Django Projekt\\meineSeite',
'C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip',
'C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs',
'C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
'C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312',
'C:\\Entwicklung\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages'\]
Server time:    Wed, 28 Feb 2024 14:18:52 +0000
```

The Error pops up when I try to create a `ToDoList`. When you do that you get taken to the `/view` page where the items (which is a database model, referring to the model of `ToDoList`) of the `TodoList` you created are being listed and you can add new ones and check up any of the items.
This is how it is supposed to work, yet i guess what I could read out of the error Code was that apparently the todolist had no `user_id` attribute which should refer to the User, so that you can view different to do lists you have created. In the code of the `models.py` file I created the guy from the video used the following packages:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Then in the `models.py` file my Databases are being created like this:

```py
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user",
                             null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

So judging from the error code I guess I have to add a `user_id` attribute as foreign key pointing to users or something? The guy in the video didn't get this error message. I'm guessing it's because it is from 3 years ago or something but I don't know exactly.

I thought that since it's searching for some `user_id` attribute I had to add it to the models but this led to no success.
This:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Models

class ToDoList(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user",
                             null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_id = models.BigAutoField(on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

...got me this error code when trying to create a todolist:

> TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Comment: You only use `on_delete` for ForeignKey. Remove it from `BigAutoField`.

Comment: Don't create a `user_id`, it should be constructed by the `user` itself. Likely you did not make migrations or migrate properly.

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` *after* adding the `user = ...` field.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem i did make migrations like he told me in the video too. Since i got a different error from that in the question here, i deleted the "pycache" folder and any files inside the "migrations" folder except the __init__ files, then reran the 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' operations. It worked, yet i got to the error stated in the question. is there something else i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got some help from a coworker and the solution was to just delete the sqlite3 database and rerun the migrations to set it all up again. Thanks for the help but my Issue is resolved.